# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' on Heroku

Tags: javascript, php, apache, heroku, nginx

When I click on the index.html file on my local computer, the page is correctly loaded in my browser. However, when I open the site on herokuapp, I get "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'" errors for all of the .js files I link to in the html.

[image: error screenshot]

I would appreciate any help on how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: You have t verify that your HTMl is proper HTML5

Comment: @Umair - how do I go about this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are propably not working when installed on Heroku. Use the net panel of firebug or your browser developer tools to see which absolute URL the browser is trying to load. Most likely it is invalid and a HTML 404 error page is returned (starting with a '<')

Comment: Under the Network tab for my Firefox web developer tools, the type for the js files shows up as html. I also noticed that when I click on the lines reported to have the errors, even though they are named as the javascript files, the code that shows up when I click on the error lines is that of the home page. So the '<' causing the error is that of <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Yes, the JS files are not found in your Heroku installation, you have to check the request URLs for the js files and find out why they fail. For instance you could have forgot to install the js files, or copied them to a wrong location.

Comment: I noticed the js files were being searched for in the wrong place. Because they weren't found, the home page was returned, and the '<' was from the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

About **Angular + Heroku**,
The error was in server.js..
My path of `express.static` was wrong..
also in `res.sendfile` for index.html

The correct path should be `./dist/<name-in-package.json>`

That resolved my error.